# Is there a max limit of buckets that a Google Cloud Storage project can have?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

Amazon S3 has a limit of 100 buckets per account:
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Does Google Cloud Storage have any such limits?  I cannot find any mention of them... but wanted to know before I made a design decision

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no limits on the number of buckets you can create in Google Cloud Storage.

Keep in mind, though, that bucket names are a global namespace, so if you create them programmatically, make sure the names won't conflict with others.

There is, however, a rate limit on how quickly you can create buckets. See the [Quotas & limits page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#buckets).

Comment: can you provide some evidence of this @jterrace?  Not that you don't look like a trustworthy guy :)

Comment: It's not explicitly documented anywhere, but neither are any restrictions. I will get it on our docs page.

Comment: NOTE: I was going to name our buckets with a datastore-key representing the customer record... and given that those keys are composites of app-id, namespace, kind, id.. they should always be globally unique

Comment: @NickFranceschina we've updated the docs - included it in my answer

Comment: @jterrace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112647/why-are-s3-and-google-storage-bucket-names-a-global-namespace

Comment: Did anyone already programmatically reserve all 4 or 5 (or even 6) letter bucket names? Or dictionary words for that matter? Uh, another idea, all existing domain names? :)

Comment: You can only create a domain name bucket if you prove ownership via webmaster tools.

Comment: Sources are not updated any more. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22There+is+no+limit+on+the+number+of+buckets+that+you+can+create+in+a+project.%22+site%3Agoogle.com