# Creating s3 bucket with zend

Tags: amazon-web-services, zend-framework, amazon-s3

So I am trying to upload some images to s3 but nothing seems to be working so I thought i'd try something simple -- creating a bucket.

I have this code in my controller's action:

```
require_once ('Zend/Service/Amazon/S3.php');
$secret   = "SecretKey";
$access  = "AccessKey"

$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($access, $secret);
$s3->createBucket("test");
```

But when I load this action and check s3 there is no bucket named test!
I am using phpstorm and the IDE says path 'Zend' not found but at the same time it says that it knows what 'new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3' is.

I'm using Zend 2.6

Answer (score 1):

Bucket names in s3 must be globally unique (meaning only 1 user can create a bucket named "test"). It's most likely that somebody has already created the "test" bucket.

I suggest prefixing your bucket names with some identifier that you can expect to have a reasonable likelihood of uniqueness.

An example might be:

```
$s3->createBucket("shleif-test");
```

References:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html (See section 3)
[Why are S3 and Google Storage bucket names a global namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112647/why-are-s3-and-google-storage-bucket-names-a-global-namespace/24121493#24121493)