# What will happen if my bucket name is identical to another person's bucket when hosting website?

Tags: amazon-s3

Let's say both user_a and user_b want to use S3 bucket to host their website.

1. both of them create a bucket named `web` in their account in region `us-west-2` under their account
2. both of them published their index.html to their `web` bucket respectively `aws s3 website s3://web/ --index-document index.html`
3. it seems that both websites would have the following URL http://web.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com, according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/website.html

Each of them has followed what they should be doing, but they don't know they had a name collision problem. How can they avoid such a situation?

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 bucket names are globally shared (and must be unique), so it actually wouldn't be possible for two users to create a bucket named "web". (see step 3 of [Create a Bucket guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html))

The reason Amazon and other object storage providers do this is speculated somewhat on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112647/why-are-s3-and-google-storage-bucket-names-a-global-namespace#24121493) in case you're curious, but I hope this helps to answer your question.