# AWS - Why S3 can't be a region specific?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense. I am new to AWS, started learning S3, stuck with this question, unable to find proper answer.

We can't create a 'bucket' with an existing name, because AWS considers S3 as Global. But enforces us to select the region while creating a bucket. I know that bucket files are stored only with in that region ? If that is the case Why S3 is considered as Global ? Why the Global tag is attached to S3 ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me split your question and then answer them.

> We can't create a 'bucket' with an existing name, because AWS
> considers S3 as Global

Yes. The thing is that every bucket has a unique DNS address. If multiple users start creating buckets with same name then DNS addresses will start conflicting. So in the context of choosing a name for a bucket, when you say global it means that it has to be *universally unique*.

> But enforces us to select the region while creating a bucket.

You yourself mentioned that bucket files will have to be stored physically in some region. So you must choose the target region while creating it.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

> “The bucket namespace is global - just like domain names”
>
> — http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#02

That's by design and more logical. See duplicate question.

[Duplicate Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112647/why-are-s3-and-google-storage-bucket-names-a-global-namespace)