# AWS S3 Bucket name already exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know this question has been asked before, but replies didn't really help my case.
I am trying to create a bucket in S3 and I always receive the 'Bucket name already exists' error. I tried any possible combination but no luck, also the format is compliant to the docs.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112647/why-are-s3-and-google-storage-bucket-names-a-global-namespace

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, I finally solved my issue.

As I stated in the description of my question, my problem was not the formatting or the validity of the bucket name, the name was also unique and not used. Weirdly enough, I could not create the bucket when signed in using Chrome, but I succeeded doing it using Edge.

One note for the happy down-voters: maybe you can share some of your wisdom explaining the reason for down-voting, so we can all learn from it.

Comment: Strange. Did you check with AWS Support for a possible explanation ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande tech support in AWS requires a level of subscription that I don't have.

Comment: oh ok. No problem. By the way was there a lot of time gap between creation using chrome and creation using edge ?

Comment: no, I also thought about a recent login required, so I did log out and in again in chrome, and after a few minutes I tried in Edge

Comment: It works for other people in Chrome, so you might want to check if any Chrome extensions are causing a problem. Also, open the developer console to look for any error messages that might give a hint as to the cause.

Answer (score 19):

According to [the AWS docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html)

> An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts. This means that after a bucket is created, the name of that bucket cannot be used by another AWS account in any AWS Region until the bucket is deleted.

Someone else has already created a bucket with this name.

Comment: This is the exact problem that I had. Weird that bucket names have to be globally unique if they are not public.

Comment: What does it mean by all AWS accounts? Like every AWS account on earth? Or the accounts in my org?

Comment: Every AWS account on earth!!...

Comment: I spent a hour trying to figure out why my database give me "403 Forbidden" error during repository setup for backup purposes. I checked IAM role, access keys, database settings. Doesn't matter what I tried I always got forbidden error. Then I tried to create bucket directly in S3 console and got error "the bucket already" exists, while it wasn't here, in my account. After one minute googling it turned out that I tried to access bucket of another AWS account, that's why forbidden. I changed the name to unique and it was fixed. Fantastic. I have to compete with the entire world for bucket name.

Comment: Why not preface org key to keep it unique?? Wasted an hour on this !!...

Answer (score 4):

S3 buckets require a globally unique name. The reason it's saying it already exists, is because another user account in AWS already used "t1-bucket' to name their S3.

One thing you can do is come up with your own naming convention. If you have a company, maybe use that to name your resources. For example "t1-bucket-myCompany"
If you aren't using AWS for a company, try your name or initials.

Comment: I prefix my bucket names with my AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. I am the sole user/owner of my aws account and I keep getting this message. There is exactly 1 bucket on my account which was created from an example project I've already forgotten about. I was attempting to add a bucket named "t1-bucket" and I'm being told over and over that it already exists. I know this not to be false so I tried doing the same thing using edge instead of chrome and got the exact same error. I changed the name to "t1-bucket-force" and it worked...

I don't want to imply adding "-force" actually forced anything.

I think there's something going on with the name enforcement rules that aws is not telling us: "Bucket name must be between 3 and 63 characters long".

Comment: if you look at the image I posted with my question, you can see that I tried any possible name combination, and there was no way for me to make a bucket in chrome. In my case the bucket name had apparently nothing to do with the error.