# Are Google Cloud project ids globally public? How public are project names?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

### Background (a different but similar issue)

One challenge when using Google Cloud Storage is that all bucket names share a common namespace - not just across your organization but across all of Google Cloud. So somebody can scan the list of bucket names currently in use in Google Cloud, and see whatever information you wrote in your bucket name itself. I'm not sure if the bucket name could be connected back to an organization or project, but it's at least a moderate security risk. (See here for more discussion: [What is "Globally" Unique for GCS Bucket Names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417908/what-is-globally-unique-for-gcs-bucket-names))

### Question

My question is whether and to what extent this is also true of Google Cloud **project IDs** and **project names**. Do project IDs also share a public namespace across all of Google Cloud? Can anybody see what project IDs are currently in use across all of Google Cloud?

On [this page](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) Google says:

> Don't include sensitive information in your project name, project ID, or other resource names. The project ID is used in the name of many other Google Cloud resources, and any reference to the project or related resources exposes the project ID and resource name.

However it doesn't explicitly say that project IDs share a namespace with other Google Cloud users. I could interpret this warning to mean something more basic, like *"Whenever you include a Google Cloud URN in an email or code, it will include the project ID, so the project ID isn't really secret."* This would be a risk, but not as big a risk as if the project IDs share a global namespace, because somebody would still need to be shown the URN to see the project ID (they couldn't just scan a list of all project IDs).

I have similar questions about Project Names. It seems like Project Names might be more secret because they are not used in links (they are more like human-readable aliases to the Project IDs), yet Google still warns against putting private data in them. I'm wondering why that is.

Comment: Did you resolve your question? This question is still open a year later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Project Names are unique to your project and mean nothing outside your project. They are not secrets and disclosing a Project Name means nothing unless you put sensitive information into a Project Name. Project Names can be duplicated among different cloud accounts.

Project IDs are globally unique. Project IDs are sensitive information, but are not secrets. Disclosing a Project ID does not put your account at risk. Provided that the Project ID is globally unique and meets naming requirements, you can use descriptive Project IDs.

Project IDs are a human-readable form of the Project Number (alias for). Project Numbers are numbers and are selected by Google. You cannot select a project number. Project Numbers are usually interchangeable with Project IDs. Project Numbers are often used in error messages and Cloud Logging.

**Summary:**

- Project Names are for your internal use.
- Project IDs are the human-readable form for the Project Number.
- Project Numbers are what Google Cloud uses internally.