# Maximum number of buckets in one user account or filtering buckets in user account in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

We are using [Google Cloud Storage XML REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) for client implementation. As per the information available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639484/is-there-a-max-limit-of-buckets-that-a-google-cloud-storage-project-can-have#:%7E:text=There%20are%20no%20limits%20on,won%27t%20conflict%20with%20others.) there is no maximum limit on the number of buckets and user can create any number of buckets. We have use case to retrieve all the available buckets for the user and if don't have any limit user can have thousands of buckets which needs some filtering mechanism to retrieve particular set of buckets.

Is there any way to retrieve limited number of buckets from thousands of bucket? or
Is there any way to restrict user to have less number of buckets in particular user account?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the bucket aren't attached to a user but to a project. And yes, there isn't limit per project but you [can't create/delete more than 1 bucket every 2 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#buckets)

Secondly, when you get the buckets by [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/list#parameters) you can choose a prefix to filter the bucket that you want to see. You can't do this with the XML API.

Comment: There is no prefix filter parameter for [XML lists all buckets API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-service) in a specified project. The reference you provided for XML REST API is for [List objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket-list#query_string_parameters) not for [XML lists all buckets API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-service).

Comment: Is there any way to use `prefix` filter with [XML lists all buckets API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-service)?

Comment: Oh my bad, you are correct!! I tested and... No I didn't find a way to add a prefix. I update my answer to correct my mistake