# Firebase storage security rule for all buckets

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-security

Our firebase app is creating a gcs storage bucket for every customer and linking it to firebase storage and applying the firebase storage security rules to that bucket. Even though it is the same rule it just applies to all the buckets that are created. So the number of firebase rules are counted as the number of buckets. If we have 200 customers, then there are 200 buckets and 200 firebase storage rules. I don't know if this is a right approach?

I understand that if we go that route we will hit the limit of 2500 rules per project.

Is there an option to apply one global rule to all the buckets in the project? Rules are deployed today and if a new bucket is created tomorrow, will the new bucket inherit the global rules?

Will GCP allow us to have so many buckets as we grow the number of customers?

One of the option is to have one generic bucket and have one folder for each customer inside the bucket. Firebase storage rules can be applied to folders inside the bucket.

Please let me know your thoughts/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an option to apply one global rule to all the buckets in the project?

No.

> Rules are deployed today and if a new bucket is created tomorrow, will the new bucket inherit the global rules?

No.  You must configure them each separately.

> Will GCP allow us to have so many buckets as we grow the number of customers?

This question has been asked: [Is there a max limit of buckets that a Google Cloud Storage project can have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639484/is-there-a-max-limit-of-buckets-that-a-google-cloud-storage-project-can-have)

Comment: So that means, we will hit the 2500 firebase rules per project limit for sure, when we grow to 2500 customers. I think we have to change the design to use one folder per customer instead of one bucket per customer. Can you please suggest?

Comment: I don't know where you are getting that limit.  The limits on rules are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits), and I don't see that listed.  If you have a question that isn't covered by that documentation, the contact Firebase support directly for clarification.

Comment: The firebase ruleset limit is given in this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the_admin_sdk).

Comment: I think you should contact Firebase support for clarification on what that means in practice.

Comment: Okay, I will reach out to firebase support. What do you think we should do? use separate buckets for each customer or have one big bucket with multiple folders one each for a customer

Comment: I don't have an opinion.  Once you understand the actual limits of the product, you can make an informed decision that meets the scalability needs of your app.  If you put everything in one bucket, then it sounds like you won't have any problems.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider that and also check with firebase support

Comment: I had a discussion with GCP support. They said that there is a limit on the number of buckets a firebase project can hold, and the number of security rules on a firebase project. So, we cannot have one bucket per customer as for sure we will hit the limit someday. They also advised to change our design to have one bucket (or a few number of buckets based on different use cases or region) and have client separation at the folder level inside the bucket. The firebase security rules can be applied at the folder level. So, we are looking at that option.